# Unable to connect to SQL server from VB.NET code. But can connect from Sql Server Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2012, database-connection

I have an old VB.NET application built using Visual Studio 2008. While trying to connect to SQL Server from the application I get the following error.

```
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error
occurred during the pre-login handshake. (provider: TCP Provider, 
error: 0 - An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host.)
```

I can connect to the same server and database from the same machine by using Sql Server Management Studio.

The connection string used is in the following format

```
connectionString="Data Source=devServer;Initial Catalog=dbDev;
Integrated Security=SSPI;Trusted_Connection=yes;Persist Security Info=false;
Connect TimeOut=30" providerName="System.Data.Sqlclient"
```

Kindly let me know in case more information is needed. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Your application is running on same server right?

Comment: No application and Database are on different machines

Comment: Then your connection string is wrong. If you want to deploy application on different machine then need to change connection string. Specify Integrated Security=false; and User name and password in connection string to connect. 'Integrated Security=SSPI;' this will check windows credentials. That is why its working from same machine but not from another.

Comment: Use like this connectionString="Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=False;User Id=userid;Password=password;"

Comment: Getting the same error by using the User Id and Password

Comment: Can you please post changed connection string?

Comment: Data Source=devServer;Initial Catalog=dbDev;Integrated Security=False;Connect TimeOut=0;User Id=userId;Password=pwd"

Comment: If you have SSMS on your application server then try to connect from it. If it is not connecting then Please check whether your out-bond and in-bound SQL server port is opened in firewall on DB Server.

Comment: I can connect using SSMS from the application server, just not from code

Comment: are you using the same login in both instances?

Comment: Yes using the same windows user to login from VB.NET and SSMS

Answer (score 0):

This should help you with a very simple connection string. I use the same basis accross all my connections to SQL. All my apps only use these 4 parts. If you need integrated security aspect, then you can add that in too, however, dont forget the integrated security will be taken from the local machine running your application.

Have a look at this function, obviously, you wont need the function itself, but it breaks it down into the parts, good luck!

```
Private Function Creating_SQL_Connection_String() As String
    Dim server As String = "SQL"
    Dim database As String = "YourDatabaseName"
    Dim userid As String = "MyAdmin"
    Dim password As String = "MyPassword1"
    'NOTE - UID = userid
    '       PWD = password, this must have ' and ' afaik!
    '       You dont need to explicitly set integrated security =false, so we can leave it out, unless you need it.
    '       Denominate each section with a ';'
    Dim constr As String = "Server=" & server & ";Initial Catalog=" & database & ";uid=" & userid & ";Pwd='" & password & "'"
    Return constr
End Function
```

Comment: you know about SqlConnectionStringBuilder? : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnectionstringbuilder(v=vs.110).aspx